Trino Insert Into statement error , catalog not available
I have created Trino connector for postgres is datalake.properties in $TRINO_HOME/etc/catalog and also readable by Trino

Here is my connector configuration (datalake.properties):
connector.name=postgresql
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ODS
connection-user=myuser
connection-password=mypassword
insert.non-transactional-insert.enabled=true

When I try to running insert into statement, there is error says:

SQL Error [44]: Query failed (#20241002_021855_00077_hpi78): No
catalog 'datalake'

Is there any additional configuration missed ?
